# Guid Non Clustered Index Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have some tables that have Guids as the PK.  Guids must be the primary key as we will be working disconnected.  I have added a INT Identity column that I will be adding the clustered index on for each table.  What I want to ask after reading all the questions on Guids as PK -- Do I need to add a non clustered index on the Guid PK as well?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `newsequentialid()` rather than `newid()` and leave the clustered index on the PK?

But to answer your question, the primary key is always an index, so there's no need to create another one.

Comment: Thanks I was just reading about newsequentialid http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/#ixzz0wDK6cece